# Probability - Increasing sequence of dice rolls

Tags: probability

I don't really understand how to solve the following problem:

```
A die is rolled n times. Calculate the probability that the values of 
consecutive rolls form a weakly increasing sequence of integers.
```

I understand that the probability will be (set of favourable outcomes)/(set of possible outcomes), and know how to calculate the set of possible outcomes: $$6^{n} $$

However, I can't figure out how to calculate the number of favourable outcomes. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a stars-and-bars approach, introducing five partitions that divide the $n$ stars (dice rolls) into six parts, some of which may be empty. When the partitions are interpreted as rolls of 1, 2 and so on, the roll sequence is weakly increasing, and all such roll sequences are in bijection with all partitions of the $n$ stars. We have $\binom{n+5}5$ possible partitions, and thus roll sequences satisfying the weakly increasing condition. The final probability is $\frac{\binom{n+5}5}{6^n}$.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I get it. Thank you!